# Multiple Serial Number Generation in JSF/JPA Application

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jpa

I have a JSF/JPA application where more than 20 users log on to the system and generate Bill type entities. These each newly generated entities need to have a Bill Number that is unique to the Department and Bill Type.

Bill Type Examples (From an Enum)

```
Opd
Payment
Inward
```

Department Type Examples(User Entering virtually unlimited number of Departments)

```
Ruhuna
Coop
Arogya
```

Example Bill Numbers

```
Ruhuna/Opd/001
Ruhuna/Opd/002
Ruhuna/Payment/001
Coop/Opd/001
Ruhuna/Opd/003
Coop/Payment/001
```

I record all bills in one Entity called Bill.
For the moment I use an application scope JSF Controller (with @Named annotation) to check the total count of Bills after passing BillType and Department as parameters. I add one to the count and add prefixes of BillType and Department Code to the count to generate the BillNo. Soon after adding the bill number, I persist the newly created bill.

The issue is that if two users settle a bill from same department and same bill type simultaneously, BillNumber is duplicated. For example there may be two Ruhunu/Opd/21300 and the third bill will come as Ruhunu/Opd/21302. So Ruhunu/Opd/21301 bill number is missing.
Error Example

Ruhunu/Opd/21300 (billed simultaneously with second bill.)
Ruhunu/Opd/21300 (billed simultaneously with first bill.)
Ruhunu/Opd/21302 (thired Bill )

It is absolutely necessary to prevent generation of Duplicate numbers as that number is used in the practical setup to trace the bills and make cancellations, refunds, payments, etc.

Please suggest a method to generate multiple Serial Numbers which prevent duplicates.

Thanks in advance.

```
Technical Details
    Application Server - GlassFish 3.1.2.2
    Persistence Provider - EclipseLink 2.5 (used with all possible caching methods, still failed.)
    Database - MySQL
    Number of Application Instances - One
    Clustering of Application Servers - Not at this moment
    Clustering of Database - Not at this moment
```

Comment: if you don't care about pretty small numbers, you can just generate unique IDs using UUID -- http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Comment: No, The customer want it to be in order from 1 onward. For example, the main cashier from one department should be able to get the bill numbers at the end of the day and look for missing bills manually.

Comment: In this case it's safer to create autoincrements in your mysql db and generate the IDs from there. Imagine all the mess you'll have in a clustered environment with a some id created in the managed bean.

Comment: Also, does your requirement also need to reuse ids in case of deleted entities?

Comment: But there can be virtually unlimited number of departments. For example, end users can create any number of departments without the knowledge of the developers. So to write to separate table and getting autogenation of id is not possible here as tables can not be created every-time user create a new department.

Comment: No. They never reuse those of deleted bills. We in the application never delete entities. We just label them as retired and keep in the database.

Comment: try atomicinteger + some persistence (file or db) for the last value (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570711/make-class-generate-short-sequential-unique-id)

Comment: I searched that question and referred atomicinteger, but both do not suite my requirement. I am not referring to a primary key, but a sequence number that differs